# CMD Command for checking if Local User account exists and create if doesn't

Tags: cmd

I am looking a single line CMD command to check if local user exists & create if it doesn't exist.

I am aware about command to create a user:

```
"net user UserName Password /ADD"
```

As well as for checking if the user exists or not:

```
"net user | find /i UserName"
```

Though trying to see if there is a way to join these 2 commands to yield the desired result.

**Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a condition based on whether the user exists?

```
SET "THEUSER=username"
NET USER "%THEUSER%" 1>NUL 2>&1 || NET USER "%THEUSER%" Password /ADD
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it is working as expected.

Comment: Does that work in case of delete as well?
If the user exist, delete it otherwise let it be.

Comment: The `||` operator invokes the next item if the previous command fails (does not return a 0 ERRORLEVEL). The `&&` operator invokes the next item if the previous command succeeds (returns a 0 ERRORLEVEL). https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

Comment: @ESingh, if you do a lot of this kind of work, it would be to your advantage to learn and use PowerShell. Microsoft has been telling us for 1.5 decades that PowerShell is the future, especially for system management.

Comment: Figured out, I have used the following, seems to be working:
`net user "UserName" 1>NUL 2>&1 && net user "UserName" /delete`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I am well versed with Powershell, though the current project has cmd support & does not support powershell unfortunately.
So I need to step back to basics & learn about doing things with CMD.

Comment: Perhaps it is project management who would gain an advantage by learning about and having PowerShell used. :-)